# Codeigniter import database from framework | You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I write function for import database  on submit:

This is one table first DROP and then CREATE and INSERT:

```
 public function demo_importer_post()
    {
        $folder_name = 'dumps';
        $file_name = 'feed_ui2.sql';
$path = 'assets/backup_db/'; // Codeigniter application /assets
$file_restore = $this->load->file($path . $folder_name . '/' . $file_name, true);
$file_array = explode(';', $file_restore);
foreach ($file_array as $query)
 {
 $this->db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
 $this->db->query($query);
 $this->db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
 }
    }
```

First I try import sql file directly in PhpMyAdmin. Working correct.

Now I try import  from CodeIgniter and:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''
```

@ update

I checked and with PHPMYADMIN I import correct with below query. https://prnt.sc/bViDzHpr5jz3

```
UPDATE `general_settings`
SET custom_css_codes = "

.product-content-details .price .lbl-price {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: red;
}"
```

But from Codeigniter I have problem.  When I delete `:` and `;`  from css code

```
UPDATE `general_settings`
SET custom_css_codes = "

.product-content-details .price .lbl-price {
    position relative
    display block
    float left
    font-size 24px
    line-height 30px
    color red
}"
WHERE id = 1;
```

then working update also from codeigniter. So how to update from codeigniter with `:` and `;` in css code?

Comment: This error indicates that there is a syntax error in the SQL query that is being executed by the CodeIgniter database library. It is likely that the query is missing a closing quotation mark or semicolon, or that there is some other syntax error in the query.

To fix this error, you will need to carefully review the SQL query that is being executed and ensure that it is properly formatted and free of syntax errors. You may also want to try running the query directly in PhpMyAdmin or another SQL tool to check for any syntax errors before executing it in CodeIgniter.

Comment: @Fransiscus Rolanda Malau  can you please check my update